# The target table is not updatable for drupal update query

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I want to update a table row value moderation=1 for specific sid value  in drupal.Now I'm getting an error as shown below.How to overcome this

```
$query = db_update('webform_views_welcome_message_2')
->fields(array('moderation' => '1',))
->condition('sid',  $sid)
->execute();
```

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1288 The target table webform_views_welcome_message_2 of the UPDATE is not updatable: UPDATE {webform_views_welcome_message_2} SET moderation=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0)

Comment: do you have this table?

Comment: ya I have this table

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html will help you. I think its a view with only read option available. Check the structure of the table.

Comment: And what about column name, is it same or do you have any case sensitive letters in your column.

Comment: same name .this table have no delete or update button in php myadmin table

Comment: Views are not writeable, they are read-only (hence the term view, not 'view and edit'). So for creating/editing webform info, you should always refer to the original table, not the view.